# PDFObject 2.0 : determine when user reaches the end of the document

Tags: javascript, pdfobject

I want an embedded PDF on my HTML 5 web page. I was looking at different viewers like PDFObject 2.0. This works well for viewing, but I have a requirement where the user must read the entire document (scroll or page to the end), and then I can enable a button for them to click on. This is for a legal compliance situation.

What types of code hooks are there when doing an embed of a PDF document using PDFObject 2.0 for finding out when the user has reached the end of the document (scroll to end or last page).

I believe PDFObject is like a wrapper that helps render the PDF under different browser conditions including mobile, tablets and desktop scenarios, and this request may not be possible without using PDF.js and customizing the code and then dealing with all the browser scenarios myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PDFObject only embeds the PDF within the HTML page, it does not provide any additional functionality. Currently, most built-in PDF rendering engines do not even provide a JavaScript API.

As far as I know, there is no way to prove someone has read (or navigated) through an entire PDF; that's why compliance web sites typically just present the user with a checkbox, something along the lines of "Check here to indicate you have read and agree with this document".

If you absolutely must find a way to ensure someone has navigated to the final page of the document -- which, let me remind you, does not imply they *read* anything -- you might be able to put something together with [PDF.js](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/). The PDF.js utility is a JavaScript-based PDF rendering engine. You can force the PDF to be rendered via PDF.js (PDFObject.com has examples for this); since PDF.js is JavaScript-based and open-source, you might be able to hack something together using the [PDF.js API](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/master/src/display/api.js).